# Read Complex object [Persisted in Hbase by DataNucleus] with Hive

Tags: hive, hbase, jdo, datanucleus

I´m use DN to persit a complex object in Hbase. The object was serialized and written in Hbase through DataNucleus.

SO, my object is a Customer with a ArrayList of Addresses and Phones.

I´m using Hive to read the Object.
When I want to have acess  with the following query:

```
drop table if exists customer;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE customer(key string,firstName1 string, lastName1 string, telephones string, addresses string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,audit:_firstName,audit:_lastName,data:Telephones,data:Addresses")
                      TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "dev_customers","hbase.table.default.storage.type"="binary");
```

The column **customer.telephones** appears

```
��srjava.util.ArrayListx����a�IsizexpwsrDN_Schema.TelephoneNumber5f�N�LphonetLjava/lang/CharSequence;L phoneTypeq~xpt 918282311t phonetypesq~t 918333222q~
```

Is there any functionality DataNucleus for the Hive interpret the serialized object by DN. I read about SerDe (Serialialize and deserialize). Is there any own for DN?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so you java serialised the field. And ? can Hive read a Java serialised field ... by Java deserialising it perhaps?

Comment: @NeilStockton So necessarily need to create a SerDe with java deserializing...?

Comment: you need to ask HIVE how they can read data from HBase and then write it in a way that is consistent